# I am trying to run this react native cross platform js on my phone but i get this error

Tags: android, react-native

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZCzT.png

When i run the cross platform js i get the above error. Does this raise any red flags for anyone? Below is the cross platform js. While the last code snippet is the index.android.js

```js
var React = require('react-native');
//import React from 'react';

var {
//import {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} = React;
//} from 'react-native';

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass ({
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

module.exports = AwesomeProject;
```

```js
var React = require('react-native');
var { AppRegistry } = React;
var HelloWorldApp = require('./AwesomeProject.js');
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: edit  with the error please..

Answer (score 0):

You are importing Component from react-native. But in latest react-native version you must import Component from react package. Change your import statement as below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: i put this but got another error. it says can't find variable: AwesomeProject